# How to check two conditions with && correctly

Tags: javascript, casting, numbers, operators

I want to loop through an array and check if each element is a number OR a string that could potentially turned into a number (e.g. "42"). If it can be "converted" then the element should be stored in a new array.

This is my code where I push all converted elements into a new array. Notice: I also want to count how many elements were "converted" from a string into a number and how many were not.

```
function numberConverter(arr) {
    var converted = []
    var counterConverted = 0
    var counterNotConverted = 0
    for (var c of arr) {
        if (typeof c == "string" && Number(c) == "number") {
            counterConverted++;
            parseInt(c, 10);
            converted.push(c)
        } else {
            counterNotConverted++
        }
    }
    if (counterConverted == 0) {
        return "no need for conversion"
    } else {
        return counterConverted + " were converted to numbers: " + converted + "; " + counterNotConverted + " couldn't be converted"
    }
}
```

I know that my if condition 
`if(typeof c == "string" && Number(c) == "number")`
is flawed logically, but I can't make up why.

Thanks for any hints and please explain it in beginner terms.

Comment: `Number(c) == "number"` will always be `false`... a number is not a string containing `'number'`

Comment: @adiga oh yes, it should be `!isNaN(c)`

Comment: @CodeManiac but `isNaN` is false for `''` and `null`

Comment: @adiga yes, but this is what op is doing is trying to change whatever values that can be changed to number, `null` and `""` can be changed to number, I considered  anything as close as  `Number()` does

Comment: just a suggestion: you can make this a lot clearer with `Array.filter()` method. After that you can calculate `counterConverted = filteredValues.length` and `counterNotConverted = arr.length - counterConverted`

Comment: I have if `(typeof c == "string" && isNaN(Number(c)) == false)` now. 

It kinda of works except for this weird array  `[{},"22",()=>{},44,"44","88"]` as it counts `,()={},` two times not just once. 

I know it's a very made up example but part of an exercise in an online course and I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3):

You can test if a string could be converted to a number like so:

```
val !== "" && Number.isNaN(Number(val)) === false
```

And the code could be written like so:

```js
function numberConverter(arr) {
  var converted = [];
  var notconverted = [];
  arr.forEach(function(val) {
    if (typeof val === "number") {
      converted.push(val);
    } else if (typeof val === "string" && val !== "" && Number.isNaN(Number(val)) === false) {
      converted.push(Number(val));
    } else {
      notconverted.push(val);
    }
  });
  console.log("converted", converted);
  console.log("not converted", notconverted);
}
numberConverter([0, "1", "", "123-foo", undefined, null, true, [], {}]);
```

Comment: so as `Number(null)`

Comment: @code correct but OP is already checking if `typeof c === "string"`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a functional approach to the code rather than an imperative one.

```js
let arrayNumbers = ["Vadim", 99, {}, [], "100", "55AA", "AA55", Infinity, "false", true, null, -65.535, 2E1, "2E2"].filter( value => value !== null && value != Infinity && value !== '' && !isNaN(Number(value)) && !['boolean','array','object'].includes(typeof value)).map(value => +value);

console.log('Was Converted to Numbers:', arrayNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `typeof` string and `isNaN` in `ESLint` way (`Number.isNaN(Number())`).

```js
function numberConverter(arr) {
  const converted = [];
  let counterConverted = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    const str = arr[i];
    if (str && typeof str === 'string' && !Number.isNaN(Number(str))) {
      const number = parseInt(str, 10);
      converted.push(number);
      counterConverted += 1;
    }
  }
  const counterNotConverted = arr.length - converted.length;

  if (counterConverted === 0) {
    return 'No need for conversion.';
  }
  return `${counterConverted} were converted to numbers: ${converted.join(',')}; ${counterNotConverted} couldn't be converted`;
}

console.log(`'${numberConverter(['id', null, {}])}'`); // No need for conversion.
console.log(`'${numberConverter(['1', '-1', 'val'])}'`); // 2 were converted to numbers: [1,-1]; 1 couldn't be converted
console.log(`'${numberConverter(['1', '-1', '0', '1.5', 'val'])}'`); // 4 were converted to numbers: [1,-1,0,1]; 1 couldn't be converted
```

Comment: Close but in your console.log there are the array brackets. I want to return the result without that 

`1 were converted to numbers: **[**-1**]**; 2 couldn't be converted`

Comment: Paste your expected result..I will modify my answer accordingly

Comment: Please put a sample string what you want to return

Comment: '3 were converted to numbers: 22,44,88; 2 couldn't be converted'

Comment: @user2132380 Anything wrong with this answer? Please comment on, upvote or indeed accept answer.